# Why only $\phi=\pm1$ are considered "vacuum states" in the Klein-Gordon model with $\phi^4$ potential, and not $\phi=0$?

Tags: klein-gordon-equation, classical-field-theory, solitons

I am reading ["Kink Moduli Spaces — Collective Coordinates Reconsidered,"](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.103.025024) by Manton, Oleś, Romańczukiewicz, and Wereszczyński ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.01026)), where they consider the Klein-Gordon equation,
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} - 2(1 - \phi^2)\phi = 0.$$
They consider various "topological sectors," i.e. solutions for which the spatial limits at $\pm \infty$ are pairs of fixed points, namely $+1$ and $-1$, leading to the four sectors indexed by $(+1,+1)$ and $(-1,-1)$—the "vacuum sectors"—and $(+1,-1)$ and $(-1,+1)$—the "kink sectors." The kink sectors contain the special soliton solutions, $\phi(x,t)=\pm\tanh(x-a)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

But why not also consider the fixed point $\phi=0$? Because it is not stable? It seems like we should really have nine topological sectors corresponding to all the pairs of points from $\{-1,0,+1\}$. And they define invariant manifolds of the system as you would expect.

Comment: Classically, the potential energy for $\phi$ is $(\phi^2-1)^2$. So $\phi=\pm 1$ minimizes the potential. Only the minima correspond to the vacuum state (in the semi-classical limit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quantum theory, "vacuum" means "lowest energy state," and the state $\phi(x,t)=0$ is obviously not a lowest-energy state.  It is not even a metastable local minimum of the energy, which could [only decay via tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum_decay); it is an unstable local maximum, and any classical perturbation will cause the field to move exponentially away from $\phi=0$.

In fact, there has actually been a fair amount of work studying the classical solutions that asymptote to $\phi=0$ at $x=\pm\infty$. However, these are a lot less interesting than the states that asymptote to $\pm1$. One obvious reason for this is the instability. Another closely related reason is that these states have infinite energy. The potential $V(\phi)=(\phi^{2}-1)^{2}$ is chosen so that the vacuum states have exactly zero for the energy
$$E=\int dx\left[\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\phi'\right)^{2}+V(\phi)\right].$$
The kinks are *finite* energy excitations above $E=0$, which makes it possible to talk about the dispersion relation for moving kinks, the interaction energies of kink-antikink pairs, and other topics related to energetics. In contrast, we normally expect that states with infinite excitation energies should be inaccessible, and the $\phi=0$ state is clearly in this category, since
$$\int dx\, V(\phi=0)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx=+\infty.$$